# How to encode a single raw byte in the middle of my String literal? (Ex: "aaaXbbb" where X is a raw byte)

Tags: java, string, unicode, binary, byte

I want to encode a raw byte in the middle of my message:

```
byte SOH = 0x01;
String msg = "8=123" + SOH + "9=234";
System.out.println(msg); => 8=12319=234
```

This is not what I want. I want the raw byte in there!

Comment: You understand that a String has an array of characters inside, and characters are not the same thing as bytes, right?

Comment: Yes, but I want the simple case, where one byte => one character.

Comment: But one byte is NEVER one character in Java.  A character is always two bytes.

Comment: You are wrong. `"123".getBytes().length` returns 3 to me.

Comment: Actually, I'm not wrong (although you could argue that some characters are four bytes not two, but a `char` is always two).  `getBytes()` doesn't do what you think it does.  But if you think you know better, I'll go and help someone else.

Comment: A `String` is stored internally as a `char[]`, where each `char` always takes up 2 bytes of memory. `getBytes()` doesn't give you the values of these bytes. `getBytes()` gives you a `byte[]`-encoding of the `String`, using the default charset* on your JVM, and typically depends on the underlying operating system. For instance, `"€".getBytes()` would most likely give different results on a Mac and a Windows computer, even though the `String` is stored the same way on both of them. (*A charset is basically just a way to convert between `char[]` and `byte`[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode a byte by just escaping it with '\'.

So to encode the byte 0x01 you can do:

```
 String s = "8=123\19=234";
```

Comment: Note that this isn't really encoding a 'byte' - it's still creating a 16-bit UTF character, but this should do what the asker (probably) wants.